# Simple way to extend the default ApplicationDbContext in asp mvc5 using Ef6 Code First

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

When i run the entity framework Reverse Engineer Code First in an asp mvc project, it runs fine and generates all the mapping and poco classes, but i now have two context and conflicting classes in both the ApplicationDbContext and the new Auto Generated DbContext.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When generating EF Classes using Code First from Database, often there are more steps as the generated code is not always exactly as you want.  I typically rename all files to "EntityNameDAO" I then right click refactor all classes to "EntityNameDAO" to match the file name appropriately.

After this, you will typically find that you have additional or less needs or perhaps even circular dependencies in the json result from these generated classes.  To deal with this, I create specific domain objects for each objective EntityName_SpecificUseCase.

You will notice I use EntityName"AdditionalData" so that the alphabetic sorting keeps each of my entities next to eachother and I can verify I have the right flavors for each entity quickly and easily.

To deal with the circular json, you will need to add this code to your appconfig.cs:

```
            var json = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
        json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling =
            Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.All;
```